# django url error in my app

Tags: django, angularjs, django-views, django-urls

I have a django app where i have the following urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.acadprogram, name='acadprogram'),
    url(r'^(?P<program_code>\d+)/$', views.acadprogram2, name='programcode'),    
)
```

and this is what i have in my views:

```
def acadprogram2(request, program_code):
    name = Program_requirement_category.objects.get(name=program_code)
    descendants = name.get_descendants(include_self=True)
    return render_to_response("courses.html", {'nodes':descendants.all()}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and in my html, i am calling this url like this:

```
<a ng-repeat="prog in programs | orderBy:'academic_program.program_title' | orderBy:'primary_program':true" href="/acadprog/{{prog.academic_program.acad_program_code}}/" ng-click="display.addprogram = false" class="list-group-item">
                {{prog.academic_program.program_title}}
```

But when i click on the href, django throws me a url not found error. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: what is the actual href that angular has generated for you from `"/acadprog/{{prog.academic_program.acad_program_code}}/"`?

Comment: This is the url "127.0.0.1:8000/acadprog/AS.SCIENCE". Gave the same one just to check if it would work

Comment: ...that is your problem then, the url pattern is expecting a number `(?P<program_code>\d+)` so this url is not matched by Django

Comment: ohh good point..what would be my regex for strings?

Comment: `(?P<program_code>.+)` would match 1-or-more of any chars... see this great website http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: awesome. please post your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments...

Your Angular app is generating a url like: "127.0.0.1:8000/acadprog/AS.SCIENCE"

That is the problem - the url pattern is expecting a number `(?P<program_code>\d+)` so this url is not matched by Django.

You could change the url pattern to:

```
url(r'^(?P<program_code>.+)/$', views.acadprogram2, name='programcode'),
```

...this would would match 1-or-more of any chars.